# paste() in dplyr mutate does not compute rowwise?

Tags: r, dplyr

this is my first post here :)
So I encountered some weird behavior today: When using the dplyr *mutate* function together with the *paste* function, the outcome is the same for every row.

Here is an example:

```
vec1 <- c(2, 5)
vec2 <- c(4, 6)

test_df <- data.frame(vec1, vec2)
test_df %>% mutate(new_col = paste(vec1:vec2, collapse = ","))
```

with the output

```
  vec1 vec2 new_col
1    2    4   2,3,4
2    5    6   2,3,4
```

but thats not what I wanted or expected.

Here is what I wanted, achieved with a loop:

```
df <- test_df %>% mutate(new_col = 1)
for(i in 1:nrow(test_df)){
  df$new_col[i] <- paste(df$vec1[i]:df$vec2[i], collapse = ",")
}
```

With the output:

```
  vec1 vec2 new_col
1    2    4   2,3,4
2    5    6     5,6
```

Whats going on and how can I achieve the same with *mutate* and *paste*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the `seq`uence by loop over the `vec1`, `vec2` elements with `map2`, and `paste` (`str_c`) the sequence values to a single string

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
test_df %>% 
  mutate(new_col = map2_chr(vec1, vec2, ~ str_c(.x:.y, collapse = ",")))
```

-output

```
 vec1 vec2 new_col
1    2    4   2,3,4
2    5    6     5,6
```

---

Or with `rowwise`

```
test_df %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(new_col = str_c(vec1:vec2, collapse  = ",")) %>% 
   ungroup
# A tibble: 2 × 3
   vec1  vec2 new_col
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1     2     4 2,3,4  
2     5     6 5,6
```